# Unable to install mysqlclient on Python 3.7

Tags: python, mysql, pip, centos

I am currently using Amazon Linux:

```
Linux dev-dsk-me-2a-efbf1447.us-west-2.amazon.com 4.9.230-0.1.ac.223.84.332.metal1.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Sep 8 15:48:58 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

This is the error I am getting from trying to install mysqlclient

```
$ pip install mysqlclient
Collecting mysqlclient
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/0e/68/f79de0e0fcdb041783124b825771e0ba6a3d0893b7b4c4735f130e42af47/mysqlclient-2.0.2.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: mysqlclient
  Running setup.py install for mysqlclient ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /home/ngvict/.pyenv/versions/3.7.7/bin/python3.7 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-odkr1wte/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-odkr1wte/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-18_ybh58/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-odkr1wte/mysqlclient/
    Complete output (429 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/_exceptions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/times.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
    running build_ext
    building 'MySQLdb._mysql' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    gcc -pthread -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -Dversion_info=(2,0,2,'final',0) -D__version__=2.0.2 -I/local/p4clients/pkgbuild-x2tr1/workspace/src/MySQLClient/build/private/install/include -I/home/ngvict/.pyenv/versions/3.7.7/include/python3.7m -c MySQLdb/_mysql.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/_mysql.o -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing -g -fabi-version=2 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:29:19: error: mysql.h: No such file or directory
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:30:26: error: mysqld_error.h: No such file or directory
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:54:20: error: errmsg.h: No such file or directory
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:73: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘MYSQL’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:91: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘MYSQL_RES’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_Exception’:
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:109: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘open’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:113: error: ‘CR_SERVER_GONE_ERROR’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:113: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:113: error: for each function it appears in.)
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:116: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘mysql_errno’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:116: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘connection’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:122: error: ‘CR_COMMANDS_OUT_OF_SYNC’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:123: error: ‘ER_DB_CREATE_EXISTS’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:124: error: ‘ER_SYNTAX_ERROR’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:125: error: ‘ER_PARSE_ERROR’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:126: error: ‘ER_NO_SUCH_TABLE’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:127: error: ‘ER_WRONG_DB_NAME’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:128: error: ‘ER_WRONG_TABLE_NAME’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:129: error: ‘ER_FIELD_SPECIFIED_TWICE’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:130: error: ‘ER_INVALID_GROUP_FUNC_USE’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:131: error: ‘ER_UNSUPPORTED_EXTENSION’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:132: error: ‘ER_TABLE_MUST_HAVE_COLUMNS’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:161: error: ‘ER_DUP_ENTRY’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:207: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘mysql_error’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:207: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘connection’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c: At top level:
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:216: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ResultObject_Initialize’:
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:251: error: ‘MYSQL_RES’ undeclared (first use in this function)
... (Truncated) 
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:760: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘open’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:761: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘connection’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:761: error: ‘SERVER_STATUS_AUTOCOMMIT’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject_commit’:
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:776: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘open’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:778: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘mysql_commit’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:778: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘connection’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject_rollback’:
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:793: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘open’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:795: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘mysql_rollback’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:795: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘connection’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject_next_result’:
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:820: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘open’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:822: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘mysql_next_result’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:822: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘connection’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject_set_server_option’:
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:843: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘open’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:845: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘mysql_set_server_option’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:845: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘connection’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject_sqlstate’:
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:868: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘open’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:869: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘mysql_sqlstate’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:869: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘connection’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject_warning_count’:
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:899: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘connection’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject_error’:
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:913: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘open’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:914: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘connection’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_escape_string’:
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:941: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘open’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:945: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘mysql_real_escape_string’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:945: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘connection’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:948: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘mysql_escape_string’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_string_literal’:
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:998: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘open’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1002: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘connection’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_escape’:
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1063: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘converter’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ResultObject_describe’:
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1078: error: ‘MYSQL_FIELD’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1078: error: ‘fields’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1081: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘open’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1083: error: ‘_mysql_ResultObject’ has no member named ‘result’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1084: error: ‘_mysql_ResultObject’ has no member named ‘result’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1089: error: ‘_mysql_ResultObject’ has no member named ‘encoding’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1092: error: ‘_mysql_ResultObject’ has no member named ‘encoding’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1105: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘IS_NOT_NULL’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ResultObject_field_flags’:
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1125: error: ‘MYSQL_FIELD’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1125: error: ‘fields’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1127: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘open’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1128: error: ‘_mysql_ResultObject’ has no member named ‘result’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1129: error: ‘_mysql_ResultObject’ has no member named ‘result’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c: At top level:
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1147: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘MYSQL_FIELD’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_field_to_python’:
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1177: error: ‘field’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1178: error: ‘FIELD_TYPE_DECIMAL’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1179: error: ‘FIELD_TYPE_NEWDECIMAL’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1180: error: ‘FIELD_TYPE_TIMESTAMP’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1181: error: ‘FIELD_TYPE_DATETIME’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1182: error: ‘FIELD_TYPE_TIME’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1183: error: ‘FIELD_TYPE_DATE’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c: At top level:
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1197: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘MYSQL_ROW’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_row_to_tuple’:
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1203: error: ‘MYSQL_FIELD’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1203: error: ‘fields’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1205: error: ‘_mysql_ResultObject’ has no member named ‘result’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1207: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘mysql_fetch_lengths’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1207: error: ‘_mysql_ResultObject’ has no member named ‘result’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1208: error: ‘_mysql_ResultObject’ has no member named ‘result’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1211: error: ‘_mysql_ResultObject’ has no member named ‘converter’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1212: error: ‘row’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1212: error: ‘_mysql_ResultObject’ has no member named ‘encoding’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1212: error: too many arguments to function ‘_mysql_field_to_python’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c: At top level:
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1225: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘MYSQL_ROW’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_row_to_dict’:
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1231: error: ‘MYSQL_FIELD’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1231: error: ‘fields’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1233: error: ‘_mysql_ResultObject’ has no member named ‘result’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1235: error: ‘_mysql_ResultObject’ has no member named ‘result’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1236: error: ‘_mysql_ResultObject’ has no member named ‘result’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1239: error: ‘_mysql_ResultObject’ has no member named ‘converter’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1240: error: ‘row’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1240: error: ‘_mysql_ResultObject’ has no member named ‘encoding’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1240: error: too many arguments to function ‘_mysql_field_to_python’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c: At top level:
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1282: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘MYSQL_ROW’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_row_to_dict_old’:
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1288: error: ‘MYSQL_FIELD’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1288: error: ‘fields’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1290: error: ‘_mysql_ResultObject’ has no member named ‘result’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1292: error: ‘_mysql_ResultObject’ has no member named ‘result’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1293: error: ‘_mysql_ResultObject’ has no member named ‘result’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1296: error: ‘_mysql_ResultObject’ has no member named ‘converter’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1297: error: ‘row’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1297: error: ‘_mysql_ResultObject’ has no member named ‘encoding’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1297: error: too many arguments to function ‘_mysql_field_to_python’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c: At top level:
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1328: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘MYSQL_ROW’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_row_to_dict_cached’:
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1336: error: ‘_mysql_ResultObject’ has no member named ‘result’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1337: error: ‘_mysql_ResultObject’ has no member named ‘result’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1338: error: ‘MYSQL_FIELD’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1338: error: ‘fields’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1338: error: ‘_mysql_ResultObject’ has no member named ‘result’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1340: error: ‘for’ loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 mode
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1340: note: use option -std=c99 or -std=gnu99 to compile your code
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1341: error: ‘_mysql_ResultObject’ has no member named ‘converter’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1342: error: ‘row’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1342: error: ‘_mysql_ResultObject’ has no member named ‘encoding’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1342: error: too many arguments to function ‘_mysql_field_to_python’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c: At top level:
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1361: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘MYSQL_ROW’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql__fetch_row’:
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1379: error: ‘_mysql_ResultObject’ has no member named ‘result’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1387: error: ‘MYSQL_ROW’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1387: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘row’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1388: error: ‘_mysql_ResultObject’ has no member named ‘use’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1389: error: ‘row’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1389: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘mysql_fetch_row’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1389: error: ‘_mysql_ResultObject’ has no member named ‘result’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1392: error: ‘_mysql_ResultObject’ has no member named ‘result’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1395: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘connection’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1402: error: too many arguments to function ‘convert_row’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ResultObject_fetch_row’:
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1444: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘open’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1450: error: ‘_mysql_ResultObject’ has no member named ‘use’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1454: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘mysql_num_rows’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1454: error: ‘_mysql_ResultObject’ has no member named ‘result’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject_change_user’:
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1502: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘open’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1504: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘mysql_change_user’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1504: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘connection’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject_character_set_name’:
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1521: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘open’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1522: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘mysql_character_set_name’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1522: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘connection’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject_set_character_set’:
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1539: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘open’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1541: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘mysql_set_character_set’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1541: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘connection’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject_get_native_connection’:
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1609: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘open’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1610: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘connection’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_get_client_info’:
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1624: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘mysql_get_client_info’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1624: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘PyUnicode_FromString’ makes pointer from integer without a cast
    /home/ngvict/.pyenv/versions/3.7.7/include/python3.7m/unicodeobject.h:702: note: expected ‘const char *’ but argument is of type ‘int’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject_get_host_info’:
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1637: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘open’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1638: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘mysql_get_host_info’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1638: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘connection’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject_get_proto_info’:
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1651: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘open’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1652: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘mysql_get_proto_info’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1652: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘connection’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject_get_server_info’:
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1665: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘open’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1666: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘mysql_get_server_info’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1666: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘connection’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject_info’:
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1681: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘open’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1682: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘mysql_info’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1682: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘connection’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject_insert_id’:
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1713: error: ‘my_ulonglong’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1713: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘r’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1714: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘open’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1716: error: ‘r’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1716: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘mysql_insert_id’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1716: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘connection’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject_kill’:
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1733: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘open’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1735: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘mysql_kill’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1735: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘connection’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject_field_count’:
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1752: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘open’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1753: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘mysql_field_count’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1753: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘connection’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject_fileno’:
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1766: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘open’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1767: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘connection’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ResultObject_num_fields’:
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1778: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘open’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1779: error: ‘_mysql_ResultObject’ has no member named ‘result’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ResultObject_num_rows’:
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1793: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘open’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1794: error: ‘_mysql_ResultObject’ has no member named ‘result’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject_ping’:
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1823: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘open’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1825: error: ‘my_bool’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1825: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘recon’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1826: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘connection’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1826: error: ‘MYSQL_OPT_RECONNECT’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1826: error: ‘recon’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1829: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘mysql_ping’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1829: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘connection’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject_query’:
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1850: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘open’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1853: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘mysql_real_query’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1853: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘connection’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject_send_query’:
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1872: error: ‘MYSQL’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1872: error: ‘mysql’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1872: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘connection’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1874: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘open’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1877: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘mysql_send_query’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject_read_query_result’:
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1893: error: ‘MYSQL’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1893: error: ‘mysql’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1893: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘connection’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1894: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘open’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1897: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘mysql_read_query_result’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject_select_db’:
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1923: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘open’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1925: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘mysql_select_db’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1925: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘connection’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject_shutdown’:
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1942: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘open’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1944: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘mysql_shutdown’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1944: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘connection’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1944: error: ‘SHUTDOWN_DEFAULT’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject_stat’:
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1963: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘open’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1965: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘mysql_stat’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1965: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘connection’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject_store_result’:
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1985: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘open’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1986: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘converter’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1997: error: ‘_mysql_ResultObject’ has no member named ‘result’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject_thread_id’:
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:2025: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘open’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:2027: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘mysql_thread_id’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:2027: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘connection’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject_use_result’:
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:2046: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘open’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:2047: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘converter’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:2058: error: ‘_mysql_ResultObject’ has no member named ‘result’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject_dealloc’:
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:2074: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘open’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:2075: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘connection’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:2076: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘open’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:2078: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘converter’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:2078: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘converter’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject_repr’:
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:2087: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘open’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:2089: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘connection’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ResultObject_data_seek’:
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:2104: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘open’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:2105: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘mysql_data_seek’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:2105: error: ‘_mysql_ResultObject’ has no member named ‘result’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ResultObject_dealloc’:
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:2114: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘mysql_free_result’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:2114: error: ‘_mysql_ResultObject’ has no member named ‘result’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c: At top level:
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:2371: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘open’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:2378: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘converter’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:2385: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘connection’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:2392: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘connection’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:2399: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘connection’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:2450: error: ‘_mysql_ResultObject’ has no member named ‘converter’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:2450: error: initializer element is not constant
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:2450: error: (near initialization for ‘_mysql_ResultObject_memberlist[0].offset’)
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:2457: error: ‘_mysql_ResultObject’ has no member named ‘has_next’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:2457: error: initializer element is not constant
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:2457: error: (near initialization for ‘_mysql_ResultObject_memberlist[1].offset’)
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject_getattro’:
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:2472: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘open’
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c: In function ‘PyInit__mysql’:
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:2727: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘mysql_library_init’
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /home/ngvict/.pyenv/versions/3.7.7/bin/python3.7 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-odkr1wte/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-odkr1wte/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-18_ybh58/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.
```

I have installed the following:

```
pip install mysql-connector
pip install mysql-connector-python
sudo yum install mysql-devel
sudo yum install MySQL-python
```

```
$ python --version
Python 3.7.7
```

```
pip --version
pip 19.2.3 from /home/me/.pyenv/versions/3.7.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)
```

Anyone knows why I still have these errors?

Comment: Maybe you can install pymysql instead.

Comment: @ElapsedSoul didn't work